# Binding event handlers to elements using JQuery's .each and .on

Tags: javascript, jquery

I need to bind a handler to the `click` event on multiple elements on the page and send the value of that element to some other function, but some questions came to mind.

I can achieve the same effect by using `.each` and binding the handler to each distinct element, or just by using the `.on()` function to bind them all at once. The latter approach requires fewer explicit method calls, but is it practically faster, or is the work simply being shifted under the hood to jQuery?

Here's the stripped down version of what I meant by above:

```
<div class="el">a</div>
<div class="el">b</div>
<div class="el">c</div>
<div class="el">d</div>

<script>
// Scenario 1
$('.el').on('click', function() {
    doSomething();
});
// Scenario 2
$('.el').each(function() {
    $(this).on('click', function() {
        doSomething();
    });
});
</script>
```

Is jQuery doing the same thing under the hood? or are they doing something completely different?

Comment: include some code in the question, not just a link

Comment: @depperm This is correct, but not likely to solve the opinion-based nature of this question.

Comment: depends if you want to do a function over all items if you click one item vs over 1 item only when you click on it

Comment: why is this question opinion based? are both event attaching doing exactly the same thing and it's matter of preference?

Comment: @rmatz *"which solution is better in terms of speed"*, could be interpreted as *"Should I use method one or method two?"* which comes down to personal preference and opinion.

Comment: The question was worded to sound as if it was requesting an opinion, but it's really a question of what both approaches are doing, and whether one is faster than the other. That is in fact *not* opinion-based, and is something that can be determined by (1) examining the jQuery source, and (2) doing performance testing with a tool like jsPerf (which is down atm)

Comment: There is an objective answer to this question. I am voting to reopen. It may be a duplicate, however, but it should not be closed on the basis of being "opinion-based".

Comment: @TimLewis you're right, I should've asked more like above now?(thanks to all for helping).

Comment: @rmatz No problem and yes, how it is worded now is a better question. Wording the question to avoid asking which is a *better* option to use makes this non-opinionated.

Comment: I'm voting to reopen the question too @SverriM.Olsen

Answer (score 1):

`$().on()` itself calls `each`, so it's pretty much the same thing as far as result goes, with the difference that in your scenario 2, where you call `each()` then `on()`, `on()` will still call `each()` for every object on which you call `on()`. So it's 5 calls to each vs 1. so it looks like calling `each()` and then `on()` is superfluous and so it should be more efficient to call `on()` directly, but probably in a very very marginal way. Except if you have lots of elements, I don't think you'll see that much of a difference.

You can see in jQuery source code, this is what `on()` returns:

```
return this.each( function() {
            jQuery.event.add( this, types, fn, data, selector );
        });
```

But in such a case, the more efficient way remains using delegated events. Like this:

```
$(document).on('click', '.el', function(){console.log('delegated')});
```

You can see in this fiddle, I've added logs to `on` and `each` functions to see exactly what happens. This is using jQuery 2.0.2:

http://jsfiddle.net/d2vev3y0/